# Magento EE refund reward points based on order ID

Tags: magento-enterprise

I am looking for code/tutorial on how to pragmatically take an order id and get the # of points used on the order and then refund that back to the user. I thought if I would just pragmatically change the status of an order Magento would give any reward points used on the order back to the customer but that is not the case.

Any suggestions on where I could find code to do this?